# Secure and encrypt usernamae/password in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

Trying to secure/encrypt password in PowerShell.

Right now I have a script that goes through several servers and invoke SQL command.

I used to have the password and username hard coded and I would like to encrypt them due to security purposes.

```
  $query = @'
 SELECT TOP 10 FROM [dbo].[TABLE]
   '@

 $SERVERS = LIST OF SERVERS

(Get-Credential).Password | ConvertFrom-SecureString | Set-Content "C:\ Password.txt"

$passWord1 = Get-Content "C:\ Password.txt" | ConvertTo-SecureString 
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PsCredential ('username',$passWord1)

$SQLCredentials = @{
    server = $server
    database = 'databasename'
    Query= $query
    Credential = $credential
}

 $Results  = Invoke-SqlCmd @SQLCredentials 
 $Results | Select-Object -Property * -Skip 1
```

Also I tried the following but does not seem to work 
[Invoke SQL Command with Secure Creds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35200729/invoke-sql-command-with-secure-creds)

```
error: Invoke-Sqlcmd : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Credential'.
```

Goal is to run `Invoke-SqlCmd` using secured username and password.

Comment: Try `Credential = $credential` instead of `Username = 'username'; Password = $credential`. And change `(''username'$passWord1)` to `('username', $passWord1)`.

Comment: A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Crendetial'. Doesn't work. How could I encrypt username as well

Comment: `Crendetial` -> `Credential`

Comment: A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Credential

Comment: I saw my mistake before, I corrected but still not going through

Comment: Then you need to use `Password = $credential.GetNetworkCredential().Password`.

Comment: I tried that as well and did not work , as I mentioned on my question - the link

Comment: Invoke SQL Command with Secure Creds

Comment: There's still a comma missing in the `PSCredential` object creation.

Comment: where would I implement Password = $credential.GetNetworkCredential().Password ?

Comment: In the `$SQLCredentials` hashtable, obviously. And now `$password1` in the credential object creation is missing the `$`. Please pay attention.

Comment: That is exactly what I have right now on my code -  and still not going through. The question is not edited correctly

Comment: To be clear, please [edit] your question and show a [mcve] of the code you *currently* have as well as the full error you're getting from that code.

Comment: all there - ji just edit my code

Comment: Some versions of invoke-sqlcmd *don't* have the -credential parameter.

Comment: If it's "all there", then why do I see a "Credential" value instead of the "Username" and "Password" values I told you to use (since the former apparently doesn't work)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some versions of invoke-sqlcmd don't have the -credential parameter:  [PowerShell: invoke-sqlcmd with Get-Credential doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51622424/powershell-invoke-sqlcmd-with-get-credential-doesnt-work)  (Actually, I don't either.)

Comment: What's the error message for the one that has a -credential parameter?

Comment: A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Credential'